# AUP points on User Profile in front-end - Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am trying to integrate AUP with K2 plugin rules are created and community points are working in back-end but I want to show these point in user profile in front-end. I searched a lot on few related forums but unable to get it up. I also tried installing Next Rank & Combined Module for AUP but none of them is working. Can anyone help me out in this. I am new to Joomla so may be i am unable to set the position or something. Please Help me out.

Current System is: 
- AUP - 1.8.1
- K2 - 2.5.7
- Joomla 2.5.6

Comment: just an idea or hint will also be helpful and i will do it...

Comment: if it's showing k2 profile page then you have to modify /components/com_k2/views/profile or views in k2 component displyed on profile page and add your AUP code in right view

Comment: Thanks Rakesh I am trying your solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K2 uses a template system so you need to edit. `components/com_k2/templates`. However template overrides (see docs link [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)) are much preferable as they won't be overwritten when there is a k2 update.

For alpha user points however there is an example of k2 integration [here](http://www.alphaplug.com/index.php/forum/38-k2/18761-anyone-figure-out-the-rules-for-k2-v256.html). Note this link (but probably any method of integrating k2 and AUP without a plugin) will also require editing the k2 model - which means this would be overwritten in the event of a k2 update. You should bear this in mind if you ever need to update k2!

Comment: Thanks George, I have already completed the rules integration(the second link you provided). I will now try editing templates.

Comment: George, I could not find the template you were talking about. There is a file at components/com_k2/templates/default/user.php which is having similar code as I can see on front-end but changing this file does not alter the output. I think there is some other file conflicting. can you give me some idea or any possibility. I searched all the directories even in administrator/components/com_k2.

Comment: thanks I got it... It was some template installed and com_k2 was moved under templates.